# Using Ros to transfer frames

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I am using ros image transport to receive and display an image. In my call back function I have the following lines

```
const cv::Mat *recivedRosImage;
recivedRosImage= &(cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image);
cv::imshow("view", *recivedRosImage);// this doesn't work
//cv::imshow("view", cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image); this   works
```

What is the reason that recivedRosImage  points to an empty image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this ROS wiki article](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages), `toCvShare()` returns a `CvImageConstPtr` which is a typedef for `boost::shared_ptr<CvImage const>`.

In the case of:

```
recivedRosImage = &(cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image);
```

.. the `boost::shared_ptr<CvImage const>` returned by `toCvShare()` is called a temporary object.  In C++, temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full expression that lexically contains the point where they were created (see the [class.temporary] section of the C++ specification).  Thus, `recivedRosImage` is a pointer to the `image` member of a `const CvImage` that is destroyed at the end of the assignment expression, and your program is invoking Undefined Behavior by dereferencing `recivedRosImage` in the next line.

In contrast, this line of code:

```
cv::imshow("view", cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image);
```

.. works because the lifetime of the temporary `CvImageConstPtr` object extends through the `cv::imshow()` call.

One way of fixing the problem is to hold onto the temporary `CvImageConstPtr` object like so:

```
CvImageConstPtr sharedCvImage = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8");
cv::imshow("view", sharedCvImage->image);
```

See also § 1.5, Examples of sharing the image data, of the above-linked wiki article.